# Azure Active Directory user Reset Password button disabled for Global Admin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a user who is both a co-admin in the Azure subscription as well as a global admin in the AD tenant in question. I need for him to be able to reset passwords for users, but that button appears to be disabled for him. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the test, reset password feature is not able for the [new Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/) which in preview. You can reset the password for users from the [old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

Note: it is also not able to reset the password for the users which synced from on-premise. You need to manage the password for these users from on-premise.